# How do I select body tag instead of id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm using media query via javascript and css like this.

```
function mwcheckMQ() {
//check if mobile or desktop device
return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#stay-content'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");}
```

and

```
#stay-content:before {
    content = "tablet";
}
```

I want to change #stay-content to body tag.
How can I change this code?

Comment: A selector can be either an ID, a class or an element name. `body` is an element name. So `document.querySelector("body");` and `body:before` (although not convinced the latter makes a lot of logical sense but it's valid syntax. `content = "tablet"` doesn't appear to be valid CSS though...not sure what you intention is there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('body');

or 

document.getElementsByTagName('body');
```

Either of these two will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's very helpful.